# Why should I use a POJO class in hibernate or spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

What are the advantages of POJO class?  I have come through POJO class term in hibernate framework, im confused that what are the benefits of using the pojo class what problems i face if i dont use it.

```
public class Person {
    //variables
    People people = new People();
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int salary;


    public int getId() {
       return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }  

    public String getAddress() {
       return address;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
      return salary;
    }

    public void setId() {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName() {
       this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAddress() {
       this.address = address;
    }

    public void setSalary() {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Please help me understanding the concept. Thanks.

Comment: This [forums](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-POJO-class-in-Hibernate) will help you

Comment: Without POJOs how will you get and set data?

Comment: @Akshay Is that only advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate is basically used for mapping between Java application and database. Whatever is your pojo class name there will be table with the same name in database. Pojo's entity will be represented as column in database. Hibernate will do all these mappings using annotations. You have to use annotations in POJO to tell this class is hibernate entity so map this to db table with the same name or you can give name in annotation. there are many other hibernate annotations you can use e.g for Primary key, For one to many ,one to one relationships and many more. Please go through [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm).

Comment: I read in the tutorial that pojo should not have prespecified annotations. What does prespecified annotations mean?